# Multifields search in Splunk without knowing field names

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

There are some two values `V1` and `V2` and I do not know index field names. How should be looked request if I wanna have in selection response the following:

```
unknown-field-name1 = V1
unknown-field-name2 = V2
```

I am a beginner in Splunk world and just tried to use  "V1 AND V2", but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing the field name is *definitely* going to be tricky when it comes to processing it later, but what you'll want to do is this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp "V1" "V2"
```

[By default](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Search/Booleanexpressions), Splunk `AND`s all [search](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/UnderstandingSPLsyntax) terms.

So if you're looking for "V1" and "V2" in the same event, you just need to quote all of the individual terms you're looking for.

Depending on your data, you may get better performance using [`TERM()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Search/UseCASEandTERMtomatchphrases#When_to_use_TERM), too:

```
index=ndx sourctype=srctp TERM("V1") TERM("V2")
```